# Only one Storyboard for iPad and iPod/iPhone devices

Tags: uistoryboard, maintenance-plan

I've just started building an universal iOS app, and it looks like having two separate storyboards for the iPad and iPod/iPhone could be a bit of a maintenance issue because the only difference between most of the View Controllers is the size. Also another storyboard might be required when the iPad 'mini' arrives...

I'm thinking of just having one storyboard for both devices. I've found by using struts and springs, all views gets resized and repositioned correctly. For any device specific View Controllers, I could just create two of them and then load the device specific one programmatically instead of linking to them using storyboard segues.

I know this is probably bad practise, but could I get away with this? And what are some problems I might run into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - One storyboard for iPad and iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155038/objective-c-one-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone)